# pandads dataframe comparision

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have problem while comparing three data frame in which one of the data frame is parent and rest two are child data frame my objective is to finding and replace true zero in place of NaN and also if the any cell from the parent is zero it should be zero in child dataframes. not able resolve the problem

I have very huge data this kind any one suggest me how can I resolve this problem new to pandas dataframe I am not getting any logic for this

Example dataframes:

```
df                          df2                         df3
name  a    b    c   d       name  a     b    c   d      name  a     b    c    d 
arun  10   20   30  0       arun  6    10   15   20     arun  20    10   15   20
kaka  0    20   0   20      kaka  NaN   9   NaN  20     kaka  NaN   NaN  NaN  20
ve    1    0    20  30      ve    1    NaN   20   30    ve    1     NaN   2   NaN

output 

df2                         df3                        
name  a     b    c   d     name  a     b    c    d
arun  6    10   15   0     arun  20    10   15   0
kaka  0     9   0    20    kaka  0    NaN    0  20
ve    1     0   20   30    ve    1     0     2  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df1.eq(0)

df2.update(df1.where(mask))
print(df2)

df3.update(df1.where(mask))
print(df3)
```

Prints:

```
   name    a     b     c     d
0  arun  6.0  10.0  15.0   0.0
1  kaka  0.0   9.0   0.0  20.0
2    ve  1.0   0.0  20.0  30.0

   name     a     b     c     d
0  arun  20.0  10.0  15.0   0.0
1  kaka   0.0   NaN   0.0  20.0
2    ve   1.0   0.0   2.0   NaN
```